# Reusing fragment objects causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In an activity Layout I am using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.  When the user selects option from the drawer list view or menu I am replacing main view with the fragments.

At some point instead of replacing fragments I need to change the data in fragments which is present on layout now.

```
ChannelFragment channelFragment = new ChannelFragment();
Fragment favsFragment = new FavorFragment();
Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();`
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
showFragment(channelFragment);

}

@Override
public void onSelectItem(int position) {
if(channels!=null){  //channels -- List<Channel>
showFragment(channelFragment);
//This will change the TextView text in channelFragment.
channelFragment.changeChannelTitle(channels.get(position).getName());
}
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment){
     FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
     ft.commit();
}
}
```

**ChannelFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_channel, container,
            false);
    programList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvPrograms);
    tvChannel = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvChannelName);
    return rootView;
}



public void changeChannelTitle(final String title){
//i tried to set tvChannel..setText(title); it leads to the same exception
    ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvChannelName)).setText(title);

}
```

**fragment_channel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvChannelName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"``
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Channels Page"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvPrograms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

- Scenario 1:
  I am loading channelFrgment in onCreate and tried to change the text. It's changed, no problem happens.
- Scenario 2:
  I am loading home fragment in onCreate. When the user selects some options from listview, I replaced the home fragment with channel fragment and tried to change the text. In this case Null pointer exception thrown. I have shown already initialized fragment and tried to the content. but the exception tells that the TextView which is present in ChannelsFragment is null.
- Scenario 3:
  channelFragment(onCreate) -> Home Fragment -> ChannelFragment; now I tried to change the textview's text, same exception is happening.

How can I handle this situation?

Logcat output

```
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at                             com.ps.tvprograms.fragments.ChannelFragment.changeChannelTitle(ChannelFragment.java:53)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at     com.ps.tvprograms.AppMainActivity.onSelectItem(AppMainActivity.java:72)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at com.ps.library.activities.menuimagesdynamic.DrawerActivity$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(DrawerActivity.java:128)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2812)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3571)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-09 23:46:49.918: E/AndroidRuntime(21743):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is null? Post your logcat and identify offending lines in your code.

Comment: Textview which is present in ChannelFragment becomes null..

Comment: Are you certain that the TextView with id `R.id.tvChannelName` exists within `ChannelFragment`? Also, we don't need to see `activity_base.xml`; it's not giving any additional information here.

Comment: Ya I am sure. I edited my question to post fragment_channel.xml. Moreover In scenario 1 its working good..

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using "replace()" for your FragmentTransaction.  When ft.replace() is called, it actually detaches the current fragment and replaces it with the next one.  When this fragment is destroyed, any views associated with it are set to null again (in this case, your TextView).  When the next fragment is put in, the "onCreateView()" method will be called.

If you're looking for an alternative, consider using show() and hide() with your FragmentTransaction so that your fragments stay attached but are instead just hidden.

**Edit**

Okay, I may have realized what's actually happening.  Try adding "getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()" directly after committing your transaction.  So it should look as follows.

```
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager();
   ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
   ft.commit();
   getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

The reason why your original code doesn't work is that when you commit a FragmentTransaction, it doesn't immediately make the changes, it just says that they will be done eventually.  Your issue arises because the transaction hasn't actually replaced your fragment yet when you're referring to its TextView.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: showFragment(channelFragment);
channelFragment.changeChannelTitle(channels.get(position).getName()); After showing fragment only I am trying to change the text in the fragment...